# How to expose IIS to intranet hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2

This is probably a newbie question. I am a developer and not a network administrator. When I connect to the server using remote desktop I can go to http://localhost and see the website. However, when I am on a PC and try to navigate to http://ourservername it is not visible.  What needs to be done to expose a website hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 to a company's intranet? Thanks.

Comment: You need a name resolution mechanism to resolve ourservername to the ip address of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the site bindings, make sure that the host isn't "localhost", just keep it blank. This is typically used so that you can host multiple sites on one IP and port by telling what host name was requested (if you develop multiple sites on this you'll want to configure that later).

Also make sure it's hosted on all IPs (*) while you're there.

And a hole in the firewall of course.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that port 80 access to whatever VLAN the server is on is blocked from PCs. Also check if the DNS record is setup for the server. You can check by pinging the name from the command line.

I suggest speaking to your networking admin to see if there are any blocks though.